# How to pass current date values from account into Flow elements?

Tags: flow, parameters

There are date fields on the Account object that I would like to update via a Flow. However, I want to expose any existing date values in the flow (if the date fields were filled out prior to entering the flow). I can't seem to make this work.. how would I achieve this?

Comment: HI Brian, Can you please provide some more insight on requirement ? You can pass variable to Flow from Process builder or if you are planning to use Flow independently then you can retrieve existing record also.

Comment: Hi Jitendra, I would like to retrieve an existing value from a record; for example, if there is a date logged for Account.Launch_Date__c, I would like to pass the date value into the Flow and expose the existing date on a screen element where the user will select dates (which in return, will be passed into a record update element). This is so that the user does not accidentally log a different date, if the date exists already.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a link or button to start the flow, then you can easily send the variables along via the link.

If the url to your flow is /flow/your_flow then you can just add url parameters after it. For instance if you create a new button or link you can do something like this:

/flow/your_flow?id={!recordId}

In the flow you will then need a variable of data type text with the name id and it should have an input output type of input only, or input and output. This variable will be automatically populated with the url parameter if the names are an exact match.

I'd advice you to just send a record id to the flow, and look up the rest of the required information in the flow. This is generally easier to build and maintain.

Comment: woops, i just saw that this is a really old question. Oh well, the answer is still correct :P

Comment: There is no restriction on answering old questions, particularly if they haven't been answered. Unfortunately it may not be accepted as an answer if the original questioner no longer visits the site though.

Comment: Thanks. Let's hope Brian has found his own solution by now ;).